# Fundemental differences between Golang's and Python's method of executing http requests?

Tags: python, http, go, python-requests

here is my problem: executing the same request in go as in python will not return the same cookies, even though both are using the same http method on the same endpoint. Here is my python code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://instagram.com/paperclip")
for cooke in r.cookies:
    print(cooke)
```

This works as expected, and should be treated as the control. This is my go code:

```
resp, err := http.Get("https://instagram.com/paperclip")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

for _, cookie := range resp.Cookies() {
    fmt.Println(cookie.Name, cookie.Value)
}
```

The only difference is the complete absence of a cookie for the golang one, and I'm not sure why. Has anyone experienced this before / know why the golang one behaves differently?

Edit: in case it is relevant: the specific cookie missing is "urlgen="{[ip: port]}:[token of some kind]"

Comment: Probably the headers. Try sending requests to something that lets you inspect the headers, like httpbin.org/headers.

Comment: The urlgen cookie is include in the set-cookie response header, but is not included in the cookies. Either the server is sending an invalid set-cookie header or Go cannot parse the valid header.

Comment: @user2357112 I did so, the only major differences were that python had "accept":"*/*", while go did not. Also go only accepted gzip encoding, while python accepted gzip and deflate. I will try to add the "accept":"*/*" manually and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Add fmt.Println(resp.Header.Get("Set-Cookie")) to observe that the cookie is included in the response header. The problem is with parsing the header.

Comment: I don't get a `urlgen` cookie. I only get the `csrftoken` for both Python and Go. I also don't get a `urlgen` cookie when visiting the site in the browser, only `csrftoken`.

Comment: I do see a urlgen cookie in the raw response, and Go isn't including it in resp.Cookies(). I think you may have found a bug in the standard library.

Comment: I suspect something in the Cookie is falling fowl of either the `validCookieValueByte` (line 366) or `isCookieNameValid` (line 414) methods here: https://golang.org/src/net/http/cookie.go.  I can't see what from your example though!

Comment: @IainDuncan You are probably right: the cookie has quotes within the value, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @robert Cookie value _must_ _not_ contain double quotes. Cookie values may be quoted but cannot contain `"`. If you must deal with such invalid crap: Access and parse the Cookie header yourself.

Comment: @MichaelHampton bugs in such fundament code in the stdlib are _extremely_ rare. If someone runs into a problem with such code he should make sure his code is fine and double check the inputs: Chances are high its not the stdlib.

Comment: @robert yes, that'll be it as the validCookieValueByte is checking for quotes: `return 0x20 <= b && b < 0x7f && b != '"' && b != ';' && b != '\\'` so will not try to parse that cookie

Comment: @Volker Oh, you're quite right. RFC 6265 does show the double quote isn't a valid cookie-octet. The RFC recommends that such data be encoded with Base 64. Looks like the OP has found a bug in Instagram!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code in my local environment and it works just fine:

```
$ cat main.go 
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://instagram.com/paperclip")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, cookie := range resp.Cookies() {
        fmt.Println(cookie.Name, cookie.Value)
    }

}

$ go run main.go 
urlgen {}:1gG5sj:plSKGgHYyLBefEhRrGVeZvPAs_M
mid W9MxTQAEAAGGiuN4IK97_H18ESVR
rur FRC
mcd 3
csrftoken LMddnPjpoVZB2p9X6bPJrGKWAzoMmMCO

$ go version
go version go1.11 darwin/amd64
```